# how to make UI items such as buttons and radio buttons resizable depending on size of the window?

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a winform application which contains a window resizable but one requirement is all UI items in the window should be resized according to size of the window. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set the anchor properties on your controls. For example, if you set a control to anchor left *and* right, it's width will change as it's parent resizes. Same with top and bottom. Note, however, it will not resize, for example, the text inside a control.

Comment: Thanks. It worked. I guess I have to handle the text on the control separately.

Answer (score 1):

I will give an example with a Winform named Simulator:

```
partial class Simulator
{
    int oldWidth, oldWeight;
    ...
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        ... (generated initialization code)
        this.ResizeBegin += new System.EventHandler(Simulator_ResizeBegin);
        this.ResizeEnd += new System.EventHandler(Simulator_ResizeEnd);
    }

    void Simulator_ResizeEnd(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.oldWidth = this.Width;
        this.oldHeight = this.Height;
    }

    void Simulator_ResizeBegin(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        int wider = this.Width - this.oldWidth;
        int higher = this.Height - this.oldHeight;
        // Change size of UI elements.
    }
}
```